I am getting extra character Â when i run sql file
I have a .sql file to create a Postgres function:
CREATE FUNCTION id_generator°generateid() RETURNS SETOF integer AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT max(ua_id)
                FROM user_attribute;    

    RETURN;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

However when I run this function, I am getting an extra character 'Â'.
Any idea how to remove this?

When I try to run this function in Postgres, I see that extra character 'Â'


your file is UTF-8, thats why you get 2 bytes for chars > 127. not sure if postgres supports utf-8 function names, but that's what you want to check.

Avoid using special characters like that ° in your procedure names - those are just asking for trouble, sooner or alter. I recommend sticking to letters (upper and lower case), digits, and a few select special chars like dash, underscore etc.

I wouldn't use dash - it means "minus" in most languages, including SQL, so you'd have to escape it === painful. Simplify your life, stick to regex word chars: letters (prefer only lowercase) digits and the underscore.

I think i find the solution here. Instead of using sql file to create function,  i use python instead and python won't give you extra character.

@jojo Unicode character ° (U+00B0) is encoded in UTF-8 as two bytes 0xC2 0xB0. Those same bytes interpreted using a single-byte encoding like Latin1 produce two characters Â °, exactly as you are seeing.

i am surprised here, i changed the format from UTF-8 into UTF-8-BOM and this character is no longer appearing.

This is all about encoding.
Your SQL script is encoded in UTF-8, but your interactive client uses a single-byte encoding. You didn't tell us how you "run" the function, but you should configure the client encoding properly. One way is to run an SQL statement before you define the function:
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';

